# MySQL Connector/Net 6.6.4 unable to connect to remote db with LightSwitch

Tags: mysql

First thanks all you wonderful people for making this the best programming resource ever!

There are many threads on this issue but I can't find one that helps me.

I can connect to my localhost MySQL DB but not to the remote one. My IP is allowed (I can connect with exactly the same parameters using HeidiSQL from the same computer without any problem). I have tried with and without firewall.

I try to set up the New Data Source by adding it in the Solution Explorer (although I have the same problem adding a Data Connection in the Server Explorer)

I feel I am missing something - perhaps with authentication method or some such thing?

[No code to show at this time. Just LightSwitch entities and screens. I installed Connector/Net 6.6.4 from www.mysql.com and simply set up a local data source for development. Worked well. Now I need to connect to the live web server and can't add the remote data source in the Solution Explorer. When I test the connection I get "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" error message!]

I think I have solved my own problem. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66647 
MySQL Connector "bug"

Comment: Please show us the code you used in the question

Comment: Look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15989284/1050818