# authentication to host or user using method 'mysql_native_password' failed

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I made a WPF application few years ago. It worked perfectly until a few weeks ago.
The connection between the application and the online mysql server seems to be broken.

This is the error I am getting:
`authentication to host or user using method 'mysql_native_password' failed`

This is my connection string:
`Server=domainname_of_the_webserver;Database=name_of_the_database;User id=****;Password=*****;Port=3306`

I did not change anything so I guess it maybe has something to do with an update of my provider? My provider is Versio.nl

Comment: Add the error please

Comment: The error has been added.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15989284/6064728

Comment: @S.Petrosov This does not work, I already tried it. I get an authentication error when I enter this command.

`SET PASSWORD FOR my_user=PASSWORD('my_password');`

So I tried this command 

`SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('my_password');`

But this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your MySQL database is running. Sounds confusing but this can also be the problem. The error message is kind of missleading in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. The problem was, my hosting provider changed some default security settings without telling the users anything.

I need to add my IP adres of the client to a list of Access hosts.